# Using state variable values after promise resolution in react

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, promise, state

I have used the following pattern in previous ReactJS projects - A LOT!

```
componentDidMount() {
    var promises = [];
    var promise1 = this.AsyncFunc1().then(res => {
        this.setState({some_state1: res.data.results});
    }).catch(error => {
        //deal with error
    });
    var promise2 = this.AsyncFunc2().then(res => {
        this.setState({some_state2: res.data.results});
    }).catch(error => {
        //deal with error
    });
    promises.push(promise1);
    promises.push(promise2);
    Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
        // Use the state variables
    }).catch(error => {
        // deal with error
    });
}
```

I understand that state is set asynchronously and not available right away - I avoided accessing the state immediately following the setting of that state in the then statements of the async functions - but I have consistently accessed the state variable values in the promise resolution section in previous projects - but in this new project I'm working on it is failing off and on because the state variable values aren't consistently available. I've resorted to setting temp variables to the res.data.results values and using those in the Promise.all section.
My previous projects have been in production for 2+ years without issues (that I'm aware of) - do I need to go back and rework that code? Did I make a bad assumption that the state variable values would be available in the Promise.all section?
I appreciate the help!

Comment: I don't understand the point of using promise.all() if you are already setting the state with the resolved values from each async function.  Is there a reason you can't do whatever you are trying to do in the .then() of each?

Comment: Thanks zemaj - there are times that I need multiple state variables available that are all set from those functions (they are axios API calls) so I need all the promises to be done before taking further action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you made an incorrect assumption; your promise might be called before the state is available. From [`setState` docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), emphasis mine:

> `setState()` **enqueues** changes to the component state and tells React that this component and its children need to be re-rendered with the updated state. This is the primary method you use to update the user interface in response to event handlers and server responses.
>
> ...
>
> **`setState()` does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling `setState()` a potential pitfall.** Instead, use `componentDidUpdate` or a `setState` callback (`setState(updater, callback)`), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied. If you need to set the state based on the previous state, read about the `updater` argument below.

There's also a [FAQ entry](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value) about your kind of case, emphasis again mine:

> #### Why is setState giving me the wrong value?
>
> In React, **both `this.props` and `this.state` represent the rendered values, i.e. what’s currently on the screen**.
>
> Calls to `setState` are asynchronous - **don’t rely on this.state to reflect the new value immediately after calling `setState`**. Pass an updater function instead of an object if you need to compute values based on the current state (see below for details).

As in the second quote, the state variables won't be updated until after the render happens, and even though you're not *immediately* reading `state` after calling `setState`, it's still likely that your `Promise.all` will fire before the `this.state` is updated—and React absolutely reserves the right to do so. Auditing your previous use of this pattern is probably a good idea.

---

Some options for you if you really want the render to happen first:

- Use `componentDidUpdate` and check that both state variables are set, [which the FAQ recommends](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value).
- Use the second [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) parameter, `updater`, which will call you back after the `setState` takes effect. This is not recommended compared to `componentDidUpdate`.
- With hooks, use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect). You can pass your `some_state1` and `some_state2` in the second argument to `useEffect` to only take effect when the values change.
- Within your AsyncFunc `then` handlers, wrap your code in [`flushSync`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#flushsync). The docs heavily recommend against this option: `flushSync` is not as specific as the other options above, but for a stopgap measure on old code it might be effective for you.

If you don't need the UI to update before your `Promise.all()` handler runs, you can save the resolved values to local variables, or you can make sure to `return` the values from your AsyncFunc `then` handlers. If your `// deal with error` handlers provide fallback values, you can return those from your `catch` handlers there too; conversely, if you don't want your `Promise.all()` handler to run if either of those calls fail, you should ensure that they re-`throw` the exceptions from within the `catch` block so the promises you save stay rejected.

(Of course, you could also move both of your `setState` calls to the `Promise.all` handler so you don't even *try* to call `setState` before both values are there, but I presume you want the partial UI update that comes from each individual AsyncFunc.)

Comment: What a great answer! I appreciate you taking the time! What I really want to have happen is: all API calls done -> use results of those calls to set state variables -> render page. I've used a "loading" state variable but that's going to run into the same problem. I can use local variables as needed but need a way to ensure the final render happens only when all the state variables have been set and are ready. I have a lot of refactoring to do :/ I've learned enough to get stuff to work but not enough to write good code :/

Comment: @ElliotBarnett Thank you for the compliments. :) If you really don't need to render anything until all the promises return, I would just unify the `setState` call into the `Promise.all` handler. That way your UI isn't in a partial or awkward state while half of your calls have come back. Since Promises can have more than one `then` handler, if you do want to show a progress bar or other partial state, you could always save the `AsyncFunc` promise, chain directly onto it to `setState(({progress}) => ({ progress: progress + 1 }))`, and then only show the full UI in `Promise.all`.

Comment: I really appreciate that tip - I don't need to render anything until all the promises have resolved...in fact, that's ideal for me so I'll take your advice and consolidate the setState calls to the Promise.all section - thanks again!